# Conditional probability and linearity

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am reading some introductory notes to probability theory and I am puzzled by the sentence that follows. After having defined conditional probability as $$\text {Pr} (A|B) = \text {Pr}(A\cap B)/\text {Pr}B, $$
the author makes the following remark:

> Another important aspect of the definition is that it maintains consistency between
> the original probability space and this new conditional space in the sense that for any events
> $A_1$, $A_2$ and any scalars $\alpha_1$ , $\alpha_2$, we have:$$\text {Pr}(\alpha_1 A_1 + \alpha_2 A_2 | B)= \alpha_1\text{Pr}(A_1|B)+\alpha _2 \text{Pr}(A_2|B)$$
> This means that we can easily move back and forth between unconditional and conditional
> probability spaces.

I have totally no idea of what does this mean. Also, the author uses sometimes the notation $$A-B:=A\cap B^c$$
but has never defined something like $+$ or multiplication by scalars. What is this?

The source is [this preliminary draft of a forthcoming book](http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/documents/6.262vdbw1.pdf), page 10.

Answer (score 2):

$A-B$ is the set-theoretic difference between $A$ and $B$ also often denoted by $A\setminus B$. Usually, it is defined by
$$
A-B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}
$$
but this agrees with your definition since $$A\cap B^c=\{x\in A\mid x\in B^c\}=\{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}.
$$

As to the equation
$$
P(\alpha_1 A_1 + \alpha_2 A_2 \mid B)= \alpha_1P(A_1\mid B)+\alpha _2 P(A_2\mid B)
$$
I can't make much sense of it when $A_1$ and $A_2$ are sets, since the right-hand side need not even be a probability (i.e. it can be greater than $1$ contradicting the equality). It does however make sense if you talk about the [conditional expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) of random variables, but maybe that is out of the scope here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As to second part, I don't think that $A_1$ and $A_2$ in the equation are rv's or numerical values, since the author explicitly says "$A_1,A_2$ events" and rv's haven't been introduced yet in the text.

Comment: @pppqqq: Does he state how $\alpha_1 A_1+\alpha_2 A_2$ is defined? The reason why I'm asking is because I don't know how to define $\alpha A$, when $\alpha$ is a scalar and $A$ is some set on some probability space. Moreover, if we choose $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ and $A_1=A_2=\Omega$ (the whole probability space), then the equation yields $$P(2\Omega)=2P(\Omega)=2$$ meaning that the left-hand side is not even a probability.

Comment: Yep, in fact it was one of the first issues that came to my mind. Another notation used in the text is: $$A_1 A_2 := A_1 \cap A_2 $$but yet this doesn't throw any light since if it "fixes" the multiplication $\alpha _1 A_1$ in the argument of $P$ when we consider $\alpha$ as events, there's the other one in RHS so we're back to the problem. :S

Comment: Could you provide a link to the source perhaps?

Comment: Of course: http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/documents/6.262vdbw1.pdf the obscure sentence is at page 10

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make sense of this. But perhaps other users on the site can. I think you should edit your question to include the link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8673/discussion-between-pppqqq-and-stefan-hansen)